# KonvaJS: How to prevent some shapes from scaling when scaling whole stage?

Tags: javascript, konvajs

I have a simple KonvaJS image zoom/pan example and now I am adding anchor on mouse click, but the problem is that when the stage is scaled for zoom also the anchors get bigger. I would like to prevent anchors from scaling when the stage is scaling.

Ideally, I would be looking for some way to listen when the stage is scaling and reduce the size of anchors so they would stay the same size without reacting on the whole scale.

Here is an example of what I have already done:

```
stage.on('click', (e) => {
        const transform = layer.getAbsoluteTransform().copy();
        transform.invert();
        const pos = stage.getPointerPosition();
        const anchorPos = transform.point(pos);
        const anchor = new Konva.Circle({
            x: anchorPos.x,
            y: anchorPos.y,
            radius: 20,
            stroke: '#666',
            fill: '#ddd',
            strokeWidth: 2,
            draggable: true
        });

        layer.add(anchor);
        layer.draw();
    });
```

https://codepen.io/aurimasniekis/pen/yZQjrN

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every time you scale the stage, you just need to resize all anchors. You can do this:

```
stage.find('Circle').setAttrs({
  scaleX: 1 / stage.scaleX(),
  scaleY: 1 / stage.scaleY()
});
```

https://codepen.io/lavrton/pen/pGQQqZ

Comment: Later on I figured similar solution :) But thanks for helping